# Sentence pattern in interrogative sentence

Tags: sentence-patterns, questions

am class 8.

My teacher was revising sentence pattern today, I got a thought of asking my friend a question that is:

> Frame a sentence with pattern of  V + S + V + O

He couldn't find an answer and asked to the teacher, the teacher wondered a pattern starting with Verb. Then I said the answer, "Were they playing  cricket". The teacher told me that interrogative sentences do not have sentence pattern.

Then I thought for a while. Then I realized that the words like what and why cannot come as S, V, O, C or A. But can't a yes or no question have the sentence pattern? Can't a who question have a separate sentence pattern?

Comment: I'm guessing V = verb, S = subject, O = object. What are C and A?

Comment: @mikhailcazi C-complement A-Adjunct

Comment: Thought so :) Interesting, I never knew students were taught english by structure in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

The seven English clause patterns are expressed as declarative sentences. *They were playing cricket* is on the pattern S-V-O, and the pattern remains the same even when the word order changes in the interrogative.

Comment: No, my teacher said S-V-O-A is different from A-S-V-O

Comment: "Were they playing cricket" is V-S-V-O, not A-S-V-O, unless your teacher is recategorizing the A as Auxiliary instead of Adjunct.

Comment: Yes, the order needs to be abbreviated thus: Aux-S-V-O . Auxiliaries are very different from main verbs in various ways - some grammarians don't even accept them as verbs.

Comment: Whatever you do with the word order, it remains a S-V-O sentence. 'Some grammarians' apart, _were_ and _playing_ are not separate verbs, but part of single verb phrase.

Comment: Battistella in [‎Language Arts & Disciplines_1990](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=p1pHqKVLRYwC&pg=PA170&lpg=PA170&dq=S+-+V+-+O+interrogative+A+auxiliary&source=bl&ots=apP1Dchq0v&sig=Qd0uV5CXFlLsmV7MsPeOqdTYsgc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KQxwUobzH9TxhQfFkoDQDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=S%20-%20V%20-%20O%20interrogative%20A%20auxiliary&f=false) uses a logical description (Aux-S-V-O) for the structure rather than a traditional label here.